# Referencing two adjacent rows in a relational database

Tags: sql, database, architecture

In my database, I have a table that has to get info from two adjacent rows from another table.

Allow me to demonstrate. There's a bill that calculates the difference between two *adjacent* meter values and calculates the cost accordingly (i.e., I have a water meter and if I want to calculate the amount I should pay in December, I take the value I measured in November and subtract it from the December one).

My question is, how to implement the references the best way? I was thinking about:

- Making each meter value an entity on its own. The bill will then have two foreign keys, one for each meter value. That way I can include other useful data, like measurement date and so on. However, implementing and validating adjacency becomes icky.
- Making a pair of meter values an entity (or a meter value and a diff). The bill will reference that pair. However, that leads to data duplication.

Is there a better way? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no such thing as "adjacent" rows in a relational database.  Tables represent unordered sets.  If you have a concept of ordering it needs to be implementing using data in the rows.  Let me assume that you have some sort of "id" or "creation date" that specifies the ordering.

Because you don't specify the database, I'll assume you have a functional database that supports the ANSI standard window functions.  In that case, you can get what you want using the `LAG()` function.  The syntax to get the previous meter reading is something like:

```
select lag(value) over (partition by meterid order by readdatetime)
```

There is no need to have data duplication or some arcane data data structure.  `LAG()` should also be able to take advantage of appropriate indexes.

Comment: I'm planning to use PostgreSQL but I'd really like to make it as generic as possible. Thank you very much!

Comment: ANSI standard functionality is generally pretty portable (but oh there are exceptions).  Postgres definitely supports this, as do most (if not all) Postgres derived databases, Oracle, SQL Server, Teradata, and DB2 (to name a few offhand).

Comment: Thank you! So, if I understand this correctly, to fetch both values in one query I'll need to perform two joins, one of which would fetch the current value and the other would filter out the previous value by the lag, am I right?

Comment: @art-solopov . . . No.  You just use `lag()` to fetch the previous value.  You can then do what you want with it . . . such as use it in a computation.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I didn't get you at first. Thank you very much, really useful, didn't really know about it before!